# Is it possible to have 'build now' and 'build with parameters' coexisting in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to configure a Jenkins pipeline via jenkinsfile to have a parameterized build (the purpose, for example, is to run a subset of testsuites when certain flag is set to 'on').

I came across the below article on 'parameterized Jenkins pipeline', and it says by adding the 'properties' step I can achieve what I need.

https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines

However from now on, the 'build now' button will change to 'build with parameters' button, and every time the pipeline is launched, user will need to type in the value for parameter manually before build can start.

```
properties([
  parameters([
    string(name: 'DEPLOY_ENV', defaultValue: 'TESTING', description: 'The target environment', )
   ])
])
```

[image]

But this is also bad if my Jenkins build is code change triggered, is it? Because every time a code change commit triggers the build, a user has to type in the parameter manually before the build can start.

Is there a way to keep both buttons, or similar approach to enable the automatic build to use default 'properties' value when triggered by code commit, while user can sometime trigger the build manually by inputting the 'properties' value in Jenkins UI?

Comment: I think your best bet is to provide default values for the parameters so that folks and 'build with parameters' and then immediately start the build...

Comment: Agree with Rich. Funny to stumble upon someone reading my article :-)

Comment: @RichDuncan thanks, Rich, forgive my english level, but what do you mean by 'so that folks and 'build with parameters' and then immediately start the build'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Builds will still be triggered by Webhooks on commit/pr changes etc. Jobs will just kickoff using default values (For lists this means the first item in the list). They bypass the params page essentially.

The very first build of an instantiated branch will probably fail due to the params not yet being known to Jenkins (Params are Post-processed, so require a build to even know they exist to be populated)

If you want to have a different set of "default values" for humans vs automated builds you could add code to your pipeline to distinguish between an "automated" kickoff (web-hook) and a "human" kickoff.

We check if its a user kickoff or an automated kick off by using the following function in our shared lib

```
/**
 * Checks if job causes contain Non-automated causes
 * Either
 *** Run by a User
 *** Rebuilt by a User
 *** Replayed by a User
 * Return true if  non automated cause found
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
boolean hasNonAutomatedCauses() {

    List nonAutomatedCauses = ['UserIdCause', 'ReplayCause']

    List intersection = []
    intersection = nonAutomatedCauses.intersect(getCauses())
    // if no user triggered causes are found means intersection is empty and then return false
    return !intersection.isEmpty()
}
```

Then you can alter the Properties for the automated cause:

```
/**
 * Change param value during build
 *
 * @param paramName new or existing param name
 * @param paramValue param value
 * @return nothing
 */
def setParam(String paramName, String paramValue) {
    List<ParameterValue> newParams = new ArrayList<>();
    newParams.add(new StringParameterValue(paramName, paramValue))
    try {
        $build().addOrReplaceAction($build().getAction(ParametersAction.class).createUpdated(newParams))
    } catch (err) {
        $build().addOrReplaceAction(new ParametersAction(newParams))
    }
}
```